# Windows 8 desktop cannot be right-clicked + graphical glitch

Tags: windows-8, right-click

I just upgraded my Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) to Windows 8 Pro (64-bit) and when I right-click on my desktop to change the wallpaper and settings, the wallpaper becomes grey (disappears) and the contextual menu does not show up (the taskbar icons are also slightly blinking the same grey color that the wallpaper changes to). I tried deactivating RainMeter, but the issue still happens with it disabled. I also have disabled my custom HyperDesk theme.

If after I right clicked I click away, the wallpaper doesn't turn back to normal until I click on the taskbar.

Anyone knows what may cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell extensions or applications that hook into Explorer are the most likely culprits for this.

You can find out what extensions are loaded using the SysInternals [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

Also note that video card driver applications often hook into the context menu to add a link to their configration utility too.

Comment: Win8 does not support contextual menu add-ons? I just found out there is a tool to `refresh` the computer in the `General` tab of the system configuration. I will try that out.

Comment: @Ghillied: What do you mean by "Win8 does not support contextual menu add-ons?"? I never said that and they work exactly the same as in previous versions. I was just listed potential culprits that are probably crashing.

Comment: Oh okay, I misunderstood your statement. We'll see how it goes with the refresh. I'll then use the program you listed if it isn't fixed.

Comment: @Ghillied (might be too late, but...) I would recommend taking a look at shell extensions first ([ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) is another great tool for this). A refresh is rather destructive; looking at and possibly disabling/removing a shell extension is quite safe. Go with the precision option first!